# Domain opens old site after changing IP address

Tags: dns, subdomain, browser-cache

I had an old website with assigned domain name. Now a new website is developed on shopify platform. So I changed the A record and CNAME of domain to point to shopify. Everything works fine with new configuration, but some customers still can access old site instead of new one.
I thought it was browser caching but some customers used our site for the first time.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this issue? Because it's not an option to ask each client to clear his cache(besides it might not be a cache at all)

Comment: did you try an iisreset? or redirect url? well if it is hosted with IIS

Comment: @devnation, didn't try that, because I don't know what it actually is as I am new to all this dns stuff

Comment: can you share the real domain name?

Answer (score 0):

The way domains work is by looking into a database and comparing the entered domain and the IP address it belongs to.

When you alter the IP address that a domain points to, it can take time to filter through. This is because of the vast number of DNS servers out there. Your IP address change needs to filter through the system.

As it stands, in places where the cache within the domain name server is still alive and not updated, it will point to your old address.

If possible, I'd recommend implementing a redirect on your old site, one that simply points to your new one.

[Here's some more information about DNS!](https://www.appliedtrust.com/resources/infrastructure/understanding-dns-essential-knowledge-for-all-it-professionals)

**To answer:** Its a waiting game I'm afraid :) If there is still serious issues after some time has passed, I'd recommend getting in touch with your DNS provider, as they are the ones with access to the server itself and may be able to fix this issue for you.

If you are a sysadmin (i.e. you own and maintain your own DNS), I'd recommend checking out the [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) Stack Exchange

Comment: It's been 2 weeks since switching, but the issue still exists. Also added redirect url on old site, but it's not working for some customers.

Comment: Here, it's best to get in touch with your domain provider, as they are the ones with access to the server itself. Also, with a redirect URL, you must make sure its not pointing to your domain, as it would send the user back to the old site again!